# drake bazel test failure in solvers:csdp_solver_test

Tags: bazel, robotics, drake

I followed these instrcutions:

```
cd /path/to/drake
bazel build //...                 # Build the entire project.
bazel test //...                  # Build and test the entire project.
```

But, I got the following error:

```
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 31 tests from 17 test suites ran. (123 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 30 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] TestSOS.MotzkinPolynomial

 1 FAILED TEST
================================================================================
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.431s, Critical Path: 0.32s
INFO: 3 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox, 1 local.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 3 total actions
//solvers:csdp_solver_test                                               FAILED in 0.2s
  /home/aj/.cache/bazel/_bazel_aj/84dff73cad498d702e4464d2c661c905/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/testlogs/solvers/csdp_solver_test/test.log

Executed 2 out of 6054 tests: 6053 tests pass and 1 fails locally.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 3 total actions
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20 and my complier is gcc 9.
Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/ajaygunalan/caf0da28ee735b2047b41fea684f8fd1#file-test-log) to my test.log file.

Comment: FYI for other readers, this question was also posted at https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18635.  I'll reply there, instead of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by `sudo apt remove libatlas3-base`

The detailed discussion is at this [link](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/18635).